# Where does MySQL store .sql files by default?

Tags: mysql, macos

I am new to MySQL and I noticed that when I connect to `mysql` and ask `show databases;` it shows a list of databases. But I am doing this from my home directory, and I don't see these files anywhere. Where does it store them/look them up by default?

I am in OS X in case it matters.

Also, if I want to completely eliminate a database, can I do this from within mysql? Or could I also go into the directory and delete the database file?

Comment: Dirs in `/whatever/mysqls/datadir/is` (or look in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database for more info).

Comment: The location of data files is set by entries in my.cnf (my.ini for Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't use '.sql' files.  Table data files are stored as '.frm', '.ibd', '.myd', and '.myi' files, depending on the storage engine.

'.sql' is commonly used as an extension for backup files produced by `mysqldump` or other collections of SQL statements, but that is only a convention, and only has a meaning to the human looking at the filename.  There is no "by default" on these because you have to specify where you want to save them when you make a backup of your data, which is not done by the MySQL server itself, but by a utility like `mysqldump` that connects to the server as a client, extracts the data, and writes it to a dump file.

MySQL's files are stored in the directory you'll find in the `datadir` variable.

```
mysql> show variables like 'datadir';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| datadir       | /usr/local/mysql/data/ |
+---------------+------------------------+
```

Deleting files from the directories inside is generally a very bad idea, if you want the server to continue functioning.  The contents of those directories should not be tinkered with unless you know exactly what you are doing and why.

If you want to delete an entire database, you use [`DROP DATABASE database_name;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-database.html)

You did read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) or [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html), right?

Comment: I see - thanks. Is there any way to see how many MB/GB a **specific** database occupies?

Comment: Also, I have seen the following command: `mysql -D gameday < gameday.sql` before (see [here](https://github.com/wellsoliver/py-gameday/wiki/usage)) - i.e. using a file with a `.sql` extension. Why is this extension different from the ones you listed?

Comment: That's an example of redirecting a backup or sql script, containing human-readable SQL statements (look at the contents of gameday.sql), into the [mysql command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) for the server to execute. Size of a specific database is the size of all the files in the directory named after the database, inside the `datadir` if you have `innodb_file_per_table = 1` -- which you should.  You can also get table data and index sizes from the `information_schema`.`tables` table, which is a meta-table giving you stats on all of your individual tables.

Comment: I get this datadir= C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\

But there is not ProgramData directory in C drive nor any Data folder within ProgramFiles/MySQL/MySQL Sever 8.0 diectory that is within